# Як правильно писати "біллборд" чи "білборд"

Tags: орфографія, подвоєння

На сторінці української [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4) подається варіант "білборд", але на сайті [словника іншомовних слів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Article=2863&action=show) пише, що правильним є варіант "біллборд". Отож, як писати це слово правильно? Чи обидва варіанти можливі?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Коли заглядаєте у якийсь словник, обов'язково з'ясовуйте для себе, що саме це за словник: як конкретно називається, хто його автори, яким видавництвом виданий, чи схвалений він Міністерством освіти і науки України, чи має він стосунок до Національної академії наук України тощо. Той словник, на який Ви посилаєтеся, судячи <s>з повної відсутності якихось даних про його укладачів/редакторів</s> (перепрошую, я неуважно дивився) з того, що він декларується як наробок однієї людини (Володимира Лук'янюка) і найімовірніше ніколи не рецензувався і не видавався, не можна вважати на 100 % надійним джерелом.

Натомість у [«Словнику української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=196384&page=162), виданому Українським мовно-інформаційним фондом Національної академії наук України, написано:

> **БІЛБО́РД**, а, *ч[оловічий рід]*. Рекламний щит великих розмірів, який встановлюється перев. вздовж вулиць і доріг. *Для того, щоб встановити білборд, потрібно отримати погодження ряду служб* (з газ.); *У 2007 році у Чернівцях було надано 61 дозвіл на розміщення рекламних конструкцій типу “білборд” із зовнішнім освітленням* (з Інтернету); // Плакат, встановлений на такому щиті. *Розміщення білбордів потребує значних коштів* (з газ.).

Також у [§ 89.1](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par89p1) чинного «Правопису» (2015) бачимо:

> У загальних назвах іншомовного походження приголосні звичайно не подвоюються…